# What were some of the criticisms levied against Hegel's phenomenology?

Tags: hegel, phenomenology

I am not talking about the criticisms from positivists who were generally against metaphysics and non-empirical claims, but criticisms from other metaphysicists and philosophers. I heard Hegel's phenomenology wasn't particularly well received and was curious about the specific philosophical reasons for it.

Comment: You "heard" where, in what context? There are to many ways to pick a bone with Hegel to cover them all here.

Comment: I don't think there's any manageably concise answer.

Comment: If you are interested, you may want to read this book: Marx, the Young Hegelian, and the rise of Radical Social theory. https://books.google.com/books?id=O_qnmE2gFXAC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=bachmann's+anti+hegel&source=bl&ots=EI2iBr4ScA&sig=ACfU3U1BME6WVY0_5FdKkJBr26EF-GIwlw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif_M3H7tPgAhUBMt8KHec2AtU4ChDoATADegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=bachmann's%20anti%20hegel&f=false Regarding criticisms by CF Bachmann and others.

Comment: As background:  the split in the Hegelian school after Hegel's death:  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-010-1067-2_4  I also include this so you can get an idea of all the research that continues on Hegel, and German philosophy leading up to Kant and Hegel and afterwards. I was surprised myself. http://www.hegelpd.it/hegel/category/calls/

Comment: I did not know about Bachmann myself until you asked this question. Apparently he did a review of the Phenomenology in 1810, though I have never seen this review.  I don't mean to suggest that Bachmann himself was a Young or Left Hegelian, but his book "Anti-Hegel" seemed to at least provide food for thought for Feuerbach.